# Django how to filter objects in Queryset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I know the normal way to filter item in a QuerySet looks something like this:

```
class GameAPIListView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = GameSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        data = Game.objects.filter(name="Football")
        return data
```

What if I have a model that looks like this:

```
{
    "category_id": {
        "parent_id": {
            "name": "Sports",
            "category_id": "bf14aab0-dc76-4145-a130-246784d1efc1",
            "parent_id": null
        },
        "name": "Football",
        "category_id": "b6e59886-e834-4612-abc7-c32bd0e2af35"
    },
    "name": "Play Football",
}

{
    "category_id": {
        "parent_id": {
            "name": "Sports",
            "category_id": "bf14aab0-dc76-4145-a130-246784d1efc1",
            "parent_id": null
        },
        "name": "Basketball",
        "category_id": "b6e59886-e834-4612-abc7-c32bd0e2af35"
    },
    "name": "Play Basketall",
}

{
    "category_id": {
        "parent_id": {
            "name": "Poker",
            "category_id": "bf14aab0-dc76-4145-a130-246784d1efc1",
            "parent_id": null
        },
        "name": "blackjack",
        "category_id": "b6e59886-e834-4612-abc7-c32bd0e2af35"
    },
    "name": "Play blackjack",
}
```

And I would like to get all the items whose name of its parent_id is Sports. In this case I will get Football and Basketball.

I tried something like

```
data = Game.objects.filter(category_id.parent_id.name = "Sports")
```

But it did not work. Can someone show me the correct way to do this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add model code, you can get a more exact answer.

Why don't you try this.

```
data = Game.objects.filter(category__parent__name = "Sports")
```

Comment: I recommand you to read this article, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/